# VBA How to avoid recusrion when using many integers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to avoid the multiple msgboxes which appear when I run my code:

```
Public Function IsItGood(aWord As Variant) As Boolean
Dim s As String
s = "|"
tmp = s & aWord & s
patern = ""

For i = 1 To 100
    patern = patern & s & i
Next i
For i = 1 To 10
    patern = patern & s & "C" & i
Next i
patern = patern & s & "merge|complete framed|width|border left|border right" & s

If InStr(1, patern, tmp) > 0 Then
    IsItGood = True
Else
    IsItGood = False
End If

End Function
```

Above is the function which is used in the below worksheet_change:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim BigS As String
Dim arr As Variant
Dim a As Variant
If Intersect(Range("G3:G19"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
arr = Split(Target, " ")

    If IsItGood(a) Then
    MsgBox (" In row" + Target.Address(0, 0)) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf + "are ok"
    Else
        MsgBox Target.Address(0, 0) & vbCrLf & a & vbCrLf & "has bad stuff"
        Application.Undo
    End If

End Sub
```

The first "for" loops the 100 integers and the second from C1 to C10 and the msgbox is repeated for each splitted string.Is there a way to prevent the multiple msgboxes so only one msgbox to appear at a time. And also an "out of stack space" error  appears because of the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set at the beginning: `Application.EnableEvents = False` and set it to `True` at the end. Recursion occurs, because you are calling macro on change event of workbook, which also generates this event, thus the method is calling itself, thus recursion.